# TensorFlow 2.0 - Graph not showing in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to show the graph of a deep autoencoder in TensorBoard.

I've called the decorator `@tf.function` on the function used for training, and I've successfully used `model.summary()` to print the summary, so the graph should exist.

In order to show the graph I've called `summary.trace_on()` during the training loop.

```
import os
import shutil

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Layer

from utils import log_results, mse, preprocess_mnist, train_autoencoder


class DeepEncoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, intermediate_dims):
        super(DeepEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = [
            Dense(units=i, activation=tf.nn.relu) for i in intermediate_dims
        ]

    def call(self, X):
        Z = X
        for layer in self.layers:
            Z = layer(Z)
        return Z


class DeepDecoder(Layer):
    def __init__(self, original_dim, intermediate_dims):
        super(DeepDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = [
            Dense(units=i, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            for i in reversed(intermediate_dims[:-1])
        ]
        self.layers.append(Dense(units=original_dim))

    def call(self, X):
        Z = X
        for layer in self.layers:
            Z = layer(Z)
        return Z


class DeepAutoEncoder(Model):
    def __init__(self, original_dim, intermediate_dims):
        super(DeepAutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = DeepEncoder(intermediate_dims=intermediate_dims)
        self.decoder = DeepDecoder(
            original_dim=original_dim, intermediate_dims=intermediate_dims)

    def call(self, X):
        return self.decoder(self.encoder(X))

    def encode(self, X):
        return self.encoder(X)

    def decode(self, Z):
        return self.decode(Z)


def test_deep_autoencoder(batch_size,
                          learning_rate,
                          epochs,
                          max_outputs=4,
                          seed=None):

    tf.random.set_seed(seed)

    X_train, X_test, train_dataset, _, _, _ = preprocess_mnist(
        batch_size=batch_size)

    autoencoder = DeepAutoEncoder(
        original_dim=784, intermediate_dims=[1024, 256, 64])
    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    log_path = 'logs/deepautoencoder'
    if os.path.exists(log_path):
        shutil.rmtree(log_path)

    writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_path)

    with writer.as_default():
        with tf.summary.record_if(True):
            for epoch in range(epochs):
                for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataset):
                    train_autoencoder(mse, autoencoder, opt, batch)

                # logs (train)
                train_loss = log_results(
                    model=autoencoder,
                    X=X_train,
                    max_outputs=max_outputs,
                    epoch=epoch,
                    prefix='train')

                # logs (test)
                test_loss = log_results(
                    model=autoencoder,
                    X=X_test,
                    max_outputs=max_outputs,
                    epoch=epoch,
                    prefix='test')

                tf.summary.trace_on()

                writer.flush()

                template = 'Epoch {}, Train loss: {:.5f}, Test loss: {:.5f}'
                print(
                    template.format(epoch + 1, train_loss.numpy(),
                                    test_loss.numpy()))

    if not os.path.exists('saved_models'):
        os.makedirs('saved_models')
    np.savez_compressed('saved_models/deepencoder.npz',
                        *autoencoder.encoder.get_weights())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_deep_autoencoder(batch_size=128, learning_rate=1e-3, epochs=20)
```

I'd expect the graph to show in TensorBoard, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56698035/2469488)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `tf.summary.trace_export` after tracing the execution in order for the trace to be actually written to disk.

See documentation for [trace_on](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/summary/trace_on) and [trace_export](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/summary/trace_export)

Comment: There are no complete examples in the documentation as far as I can see. Did not yet work.

Comment: Right before you leave `writer.as_default()`, call `tf.summary.trace_export("graph", 0)` <- EDIT fix

Also, there's a typo in the implementation of DeepAutoEncoder::decode (it calls itself)