# How to graph tf.keras model in Tensorflow-2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I upgraded to Tensorflow 2.0 and there is no `tf.summary.FileWriter("tf_graphs", sess.graph)`. I was looking through some other StackOverflow questions on this and they said to use `tf.compat.v1.summary etc`. Surely there must be a way to graph and visualize a tf.keras model in Tensorflow version 2. What is it? I'm looking for a tensorboard output like the one below. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/graphs#op-level_graph), you can use Tensorboard to visualise graphs once your model has been trained.

First, define your model and run it. Then, open Tensorboard and switch to the Graph tab.

---

**Minimal Compilable Example**

This example is taken from the docs. First, define your model and data.

```
# Relevant imports.
%load_ext tensorboard

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from datetime import datetime
from packaging import version

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Define the model.
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

(train_images, train_labels), _ = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images / 255.0
```

Next, train your model. Here, you will need to define a callback for Tensorboard to use for visualising stats and graphs.

```
# Define the Keras TensorBoard callback.
logdir="logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

# Train the model.
model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels, 
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=5, 
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

After training, in your notebook, run

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs
```

And switch to the Graph tab in the navbar:

[image]

You will see a graph that looks a lot like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to visualize it without training it first?

Comment: @ColinSteidtmann I've looked at multiple GitHub issues and the consensus seems to be that this is not supported for keras models as of now because of eager execution enabled by default.

Comment: Darn, thanks for the lookup. I know it's still in beta so I'll just be patient.

Comment: This is not entirely correct, you can convert to graph and visualize the model without training it. See my answer

Comment: @nessuno you still have to run the model with some amount of data. Granted it is a single sample, it feels somewhat hacky to me. I searched for hours and found nothing simpler than this and gave up.

Comment: Yes that's right. Executing the model is required since the graph is built by tracing the execution, but there is no need to train the model, you can just use `tf.function` and run the forward pass (if you're interested in seeing only that part, and not the graph of the training loop)

Comment: Hello guys, I am wondering what's the difference of 'Main Graph'/'Auxiliary Nodes'/'Functions'？ It cost me hours to find the meaning from tensorflow documents but get nothing.

Answer (score 29):

You can visualize the graph of any `tf.function` decorated function, but first, you have to trace its execution.

Visualizing the graph of a Keras model means to visualize it's `call` method.

By default, this method is not `tf.function` decorated and therefore you have to wrap the model call in a function correctly decorated and execute it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)


@tf.function
def traceme(x):
    return model(x)


logdir = "log"
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
# Forward pass
traceme(tf.zeros((1, 28, 28, 1)))
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(name="model_trace", step=0, profiler_outdir=logdir)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! I can however still not access the run information in TensorBoard. Yes, profiler is set to true. Any idea?

Comment: The profiling itself. Tensorboard does not display any runtime information, e.g. how long the execution of the nodes in my graph took or the memory consumption. If it is shown for you, maybe there is another problem for me.

Comment: My only suggestion is to read this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras and to use Chromium/Chrome (yes, other browsers can't be used because the profile uses certain parts of chrome)

Comment: ```ProfilerNotRunningError: Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.``` on Windows. Any help please?

Comment: `ProfilerNotRunningError: Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.` also on Linux

Comment: @Crispy13 Wrapping the call to `tf.summary.trace_export` in a `try: except: pass` solved it for me, no idea why though

Comment: Great! And if you just only want the graph, you can set `profiler=False`.

Comment: Strange that is works with 4D tensor. Actual input is 3D tensor with shape `(None, 28, 28)`. Hence, traceme should be called the following way `traceme(tf.zeros((1, 28, 28)))`

Comment: Nope, the input is not statically defined and the model is created on the first run. You're confusing the (28,28) in the flatten layer with the input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for **tf2.x** with [Graph visualization of **subclassed model/layer**](https://https://fantashit.com/graph-visualization-of-subclassed-model-layer/)

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model,Input


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
        self.conv3 = Conv2D(8, 3, activation='relu')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(1)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)
    def build_graph(self):
        x = Input(shape=(dim))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))


dim = (28, 28, 1)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel((dim))
model.build((None, *dim))
model.build_graph().summary()


tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model.build_graph(), to_file="model.png",
           expand_nested=True, show_shapes=True)
```

**the output is**

```
TensorFlow version: 2.5.0

Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 22, 22, 8)         2312      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3872)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               495744    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 502,985
Trainable params: 502,985
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is also a **graph visualization**

[image: Here is also a graph visualization]

Comment: another example Plot Model Architecture - General Discussion - TensorFlow Forum
https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/plot-model-architecture/3700

Answer (score 1):

Here's what is working for me at the moment (TF 2.0.0), based on the [tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard) code:

```
# After model has been compiled
from tensorflow.python.ops import summary_ops_v2
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import get_graph
tb_path = '/tmp/tensorboard/'
tb_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(tb_path)
with tb_writer.as_default():
    if not model.run_eagerly:
        summary_ops_v2.graph(get_graph(), step=0)
```

Comment: What is `tb_writer`?

Comment: A tf.summary.SummaryWriter object. Edited the code to define it

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use this website: https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/

which generate a graph with a .h5 or .tflite file.

The github repo it's based on may be found here (which also has a python interface):
https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron